# NetSuite - Date Issues

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

My due date returns a date while my current date returns a date and time. I get the error below when trying to call function that needs date/time. How do I construct me due date to include the time?

Error: **due_date.getTime is not a function**

```js
var current_date = nlapiDateToString(new Date(), 'datetime')
var dd = nlapiGetFieldValue('duedate');
var due_date = nlapiDateToString(new Date(), dd)

var days_overdue = DateOverdue(current_date, due_date);

function DateOverdue(current_date, due_date) {
  var time_difference = Math.abs(due_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime());
  var no_days_overdue_by = Math.ceil(time_difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  alert("No of Days Overdue By... " + no_days_overdue_by);
  return no_days_overdue_by;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to run date functions on strings. You set the dates to strings with the nlapiDateToString() function.  Wrap those in nlapiStringToDate() functions and that will fix the issue you are having.  Below is a sample of that using your code.

```
var current_date=nlapiStringToDate(nlapiDateToString(new Date(),'datetime'));
var dd='7/19/2016';//nlapiGetFieldValue('duedate');
var due_date=nlapiStringToDate(dd);
var days_overdue=DateOverdue(current_date,due_date);

function DateOverdue(current_date,due_date){
  var time_difference=Math.abs(due_date.getTime()-current_date.getTime());
  var no_days_overdue_by=Math.ceil(time_difference/(1000*3600*24));
  alert("No of Days Overdue By... "+no_days_overdue_by);
  return no_days_overdue_by;
}
```

This outputs: "warning  No of Days Overdue By... 32"

Comment: While the code works now - there appears to be an odd calculation. So if the days overdue date is 17th Aug and today's date is 19th - I would have expected my function to return 2. Instead it returns 3. When I use the days overdue field in a search I see 3. gong to guess that days overdue is using 2 different time zones?

Comment: That is very possible.  If I run it with those two dates hard-coded, I get 2.  Add in some logging through it and see what it is spitting out through the scripts.  That should give you the answer.